# ImageView panGesture cancelling UISCrollVIew scroll feature

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I' ve got a scroll view in which I have multiple image views on which I am applying pan gesture to drag the image view and add to the other view. The problem is that when I try to scroll the scroll view the pan gesture is recognised first and the panning action is called rather than the scroll view to scrolling.
this is my code for the panning

```
-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    [[baseView superview]  bringSubviewToFront:baseView]; //sender.view];

    [hatScroll setScrollEnabled:NO];

    // We pass in the gesture to a method that will help us align our touches so that the pan and pinch will seems to originate between the fingers instead of other points or center point of the UIView
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:sender];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        if ([[[sender view] superview] superview] == itemView || [[[sender view] superview] superview] == itemView_iphone5) // adds the imageview in the item scroll
        {
            int tag = [[sender view] tag] / 100;
            UIScrollView *tempScroll;

            if (window.bounds.size.height != 568)
                tempScroll = (UIScrollView *)[itemView viewWithTag:-tag];
            else
                tempScroll = (UIScrollView *)[itemView_iphone5 viewWithTag:-tag];
            CGRect frame = CGRectFromString([itemFrameDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[sender view] tag]]]);

            CGAffineTransform transform = temp.transform;
            UIImageView *tempImageView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [(UIImageView *) [sender view] image]];
            tempImageView.tag = [[sender view] tag];
            tempImageView.frame = frame;
            [tempImageView setTransform:transform];
            [tempImageView setFrame:frame];
            [tempImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [tempScroll addSubview:tempImageView];

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
            panRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            panRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
            panRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
            [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
        }
    }

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translatedPoint = [sender locationInView:[[sender view] superview]] ;
        newTranslatedPoint = [[[sender view] superview] convertPoint:translatedPoint toView:baseView];

        if (window.bounds.size.height != 568)
        {
            if ([sender view].frame.size.width == 35 && [sender view].frame.size.height == 35)
                [[sender view] sizeToFit];
        }
        else
        {
            if ([sender view].frame.size.width == 45 && [sender view].frame.size.height == 45)
                [[sender view] sizeToFit];
        }


        [sender view].center =  CGPointMake(newTranslatedPoint.x, newTranslatedPoint.y);

        [baseView addSubview:[sender view]];
    }

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        [hatScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

        [self.view insertSubview:baseView atIndex:2];



        CGPoint newPoint;
        if (window.bounds.size.height != 568)
            newPoint = [[[sender view] superview] convertPoint:newTranslatedPoint toView:itemView];
        else
            newPoint = [[[sender view] superview] convertPoint:newTranslatedPoint toView:itemView_iphone5];

        if (newPoint.y < 0)
        {

            UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
            [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [[sender view] addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

            UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
            [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [[sender view] addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];


        }

        else if (newPoint.y > 0)
        {

            int tag = [[sender view] tag] / 100;

            UIScrollView *tempScroll;

            if (window.bounds.size.height != 568)
                tempScroll = (UIScrollView *)[itemView viewWithTag:-tag];
            else
                tempScroll = (UIScrollView *)[itemView_iphone5 viewWithTag:-tag];

            CGRect frame = CGRectFromString([itemFrameDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[sender view] tag]]]);

            CGAffineTransform transform = temp.transform;
            [[sender view] setTransform:transform];
            [[sender view] setFrame:frame];
            [tempScroll addSubview:[sender view]];

        }
    }
}
```

any ideas? how can I get this. Feel free to ask query at the mentioned code.

Comment: if u want to pass the gestures to the scroll view to which uiimageview is added. simple set [tempImageView setUserInteraction:NO];

Comment: then how will the pangesture work which is given to imgaeview

Comment: nothing to do with Xcode, xcode is the IDE only -- not the sdk, nor api nor language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using long press gesture to drag that particular item from the scrollview